# Display my images in ebay listings (or other website) .htaccess question

Tags: magento2, htaccess, .htaccess, magento2.4.3

I have a Magento site (2.4.3) running on Ubuntu with Apache. I am creating eBay listings which are using images from the https://<mysite.com>/images folder. The images are not displayed. If I try to open the URL https://<mysite.com>/images/MyImage.jpg, I am displayed the Magento 404 page.

My .htaccess file is the default version

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If I add this code to the file, I can get the images to work but it breaks the Magento site. Note: I've added spaces as the second character of line 1 and 3 below because I could not get the code to display correctly without them.

```
< Directory "Your directory path/images/">

   Allow from all

< /Directory>
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this one myself with a little trial and error. I added a line into the .htaccess file so it now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*$   <-- Added this line
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```